# How to fix mean times series

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, variance

a time ago I measured air pollution with a device I made and this is the plotted data, and it seems that the pollution remained in the device over time. There is a way to fix the increasing mean? it is posible without transforming the data?

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Clean the device. Right now, you have a hypothesis that lacks evidence.

Comment: What would it mean to "fix the mean without transforming the data"?

Comment: Good point, I'll clean it. What I meant was, without changing the original values using like log transformation, differentiation, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are probably interested in the seasonality component as shown in the attached image. You can find more about how to do this in R in [this simple stats book](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/6/1)

[image: time series decomposition]